# What would be arithmetic hierarchy of $\Sigma_1^0 \wedge \Pi_1^0$?

Tags: logic, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

What would be arithmetic hierarchy of the form of formula like $\phi \wedge \psi$ where $\phi$ is $\Sigma_1^0$ and $\psi$ is $\Pi_1^0$? Prenex normal form seems to give me no answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\Pi^0_1,\Sigma^0_1\subseteq\Delta^0_2$, and the latter is closed under finite conjunctions, that would be the minimal possibly answer.

Comment: Oh, and what will happen then if $\psi$ is $\Sigma_1^0$ and $\phi$ is $\Sigma_2^0$? And what if $\psi$ is $\Pi_1^0$ and $\phi$ is $\Pi_2^0$?

Comment: @UQT: You might want to learn a bit about the inclusions of the sets in the arithmetical hierarchy, and their closure properties.

Comment: Right. Thanks very much.